# Including reset margin/padding inside CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, accordion, reset

I was not sure how to word this question, so forgive me ahead of time.

Basically, I have used an accordion template for a vertical menu on my wordpress theme, and I've got it set up - however, in the code there is a reset:

**Code A**

```
/*---- basic reset--*/
* { 
margin: 0; 
padding:0; }
```

this is at the very top of my style for the navigation, the rest of the style is as follows:

**Code B**

```
/*heading styles*/
#accordian h3 {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 34px;
cursor: pointer;
/*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
background: #1f84ba; 
background: linear-gradient(#1f84ba, #156691);
}

/*heading hover effect*/
#accordian h3:hover {
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

/*list items*/
#accordian li {
list-style-type: none;
}
/*links*/
#accordian ul ul li a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 11px;
line-height: 27px;
display: block;
padding: 0 15px;
/*transition for smooth hover animation*/
transition: all 0.15s;
}

/*hover effect on links*/
#accordian ul ul li a:hover {
background: #003545;
border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;
}

/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
#accordian ul ul {
display: none;
}

#accordian li.active ul {
display: block;
}
```

below is my edit, this is to be included at the top of Code B.

**Code C (Edit)**

```
#accordian {
background: #1f84ba;
width: 225px;
color: white;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
```

Having the basic reset at the top of the page (Code A) seems to apply it to the whole page (I presume that is what the * means, but I am a new user of CSS)

I only want it to apply to the navigation (#accordion) so that it doesn't change the margins and padding on my whole page.

Thanks a lot, I know this is probably very simple - and I hope it doesn't cause to much effort!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you can just change `*` to `#accordian`. example:

```
/*---- basic reset--*/
#accordian { 
margin: 0; 
padding:0; }
```

***Update***

Remove the following code completely:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }
```

Then, assuming you want no margins or padding on your navigation, change the code you supplied in your update (Code C) to:

```
#accordian {
background: #1f84ba;
width: 225px;
color: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Don't forget your order of operations either. I've been thrown a ton of times only to realize that I had conflicting code toward the bottom. If in doubt, add `!important` to the margin and padding options and see if that makes a difference. If it does, you'll be safe to assume there is some conflicting code somewhere.

example:

```
#accordian {
background: #1f84ba;
width: 225px;
color: white;
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `*` is called the "universal selector", meaning it selects all elements. Using it to reset padding and margin isn't a good idea, as it has ill effects on some elements (like form elements), so it's not recommended any more.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally excluded a tiny piece of code in my Code B CSS. I have now included this in my main post under Code C (Edit). I have a #accordion tag already, and I have tried including it as you stated but with no luck. It may be because of the margin: tag that is already present, I am not sure how to edit around that.

Thanks for the quick response

Comment: For some reason, I feel as if this should be working, I just cant understand why it is not.

Comment: @Colin Do you still have the reset in your code? Like ralph.m said earlier, using the universal selector on margins probably isn't best practice. Since you are trying to override it anyways, you may as well delete it. Also, don't forget that CSS is cascading, meaning that the code works it's way from top to bottom and will overwrite itself. The last instance of `#navigation` will always be the one applied, unless of course you have `!important` somewhere. See the updates in my answer for some more options...